# Can I extract labels of an image dataset from image names using Keras for CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to design a CNN model to classify an image dataset with 200,000 different fonts and Alphabet. images are in 8 different folders and the folder names are class 1 to class 8. I want to classify images in this folder to know what alphabet the images show. how can I do that without having any file that shows the alphabet?

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  directory, label = None, 
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(32, 32),
  batch_size=batch_size
  )
```

I use this code to use my dataset for training and validation.
my directory is like this

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
.
.
......a_image_1000.jpg
......b_image_1.jpg
.
......b_image_1000.jpg
.
.
.
......y_image_1.jpg
.
.
......y_image_1000.jpg
......z_image_1.jpg
.
.
......z_image_1000.jpg
...class_b/
......a_image_1000.jpg
.
.
......a_image_2000.jpg
......b_image_1000.jpg
.
......b_image_2000.jpg
.
.
.
......y_image_1000.jpg
.
.
......y_image_2000.jpg
......z_image_1000.jpg
.
.
......z_image_2000.jpg
```

and this doesn't let me see labels with `train_ds`

Comment: here keras use labels based on directory segregation, hope you have seen examples
FYI 
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras/

Comment: if you use train_ds.classes you would be able to see the labels i guess, did you check this ?

Comment: @Nagakiran the main problem is that the names of folders are not the labels. the label of each image is the image name. so train_ds.classes can't find those labels

Comment: Please use manual program with os, shutil to segregate images based name label, keras won't load whole training data at once, so only folder structure, it can't have naming based disintegration.

Comment: @Nagakiran thank you, for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras usually wont load all data once to save memory,  it can't have [naming disintegration.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory)

as files are unsorted you can try using below snippet with `shutil` and `os` to segregate the files accordingly and load folder based [data generators](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-large-datasets-from-directories-for-deep-learning-with-keras/) to feed data to model

```
import os
from shutil import move

folder = 'data folder path'
for clas in os.listdir(folder):
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(folder, clas)):
        class_label = file.split('_')[0]
        class_folder = os.path.join(folder, 'class_{}'.format(class_label))
        os.makedirs(class_folder, exist_ok=True)
        move(os.path.join(folder,clas, file), os.path.join(folder, class_folder, file))




# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/train/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)
# load and iterate validation dataset
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/validation/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)
# load and iterate test dataset
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('data/test/', class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)
```